# Comparing three .csv files and outputting similarities

Tags: bash, csv

I am working on a project in bash script to read three different .csv files and output the similar rows. 
The three .csv files are formated the same way with the same information but the second column may be different.
For example, if I have three csv files, named A.csv, B.csv, and C.csv.

```
A.csv
Animal, Color, Age
Dog, Brown, 9
Cow, White, 3
Cat, Black, 5
Parrot, Blue, 2

B.csv
Animal, Color, Age
Dog, Black, 9
Cow, White, 3
Cat, Brown, 5
Parrot, Blue, 2

C.csv
Animal, Color, Age
Dog, Brown, 9
Cow, White, 3
Cat, Tan, 5
Parrot, Blue, 2
```

After running the program, I am looking to get an output like:

```
Animal, Color, Age
Cow, White, 3
Parrot, Blue 2
```

I have read up on diff3 but that only outputs the differences which is the opposite of what I am trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Using `grep`:

```
grep A.csv -f B.csv | grep -f C.csv
```

grep `-f FILE` gets the patterns from the FILE.

*Output:*

```
Animal, Color, Age
Cow, White, 3
Parrot, Blue, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[$0]++;next}
FILENAME==ARGV[2] && ($0 in a){b[$0]++;next} 
$0 in b' A.csv B.csv C.csv
```

#### Output from your sample files:

```
Animal, Color, Age
Cow, White, 3
Parrot, Blue, 2
```

Comment: hi, this solution works when I run it however, it outputs in a way where the last item on one row is connected to the first item in the next row. so from the example, if you look at the .csv file from a notepad you would get:
Animal, Color, AgeCow, White, 3Parrot, Blue, 2

I was wondering how i could get a linebreak at the end of the each row. thanks

Comment: `awk '
FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[$0]++;next}
FILENAME==ARGV[2] && ($0 in a){b[$0]++;next} 
$0 in b{sub(/$/,"\r");}1' A.csv B.csv C.csv` should help

Comment: Hi, it seems to work however, the orer of the rows are off now.

Comment: Since it is a three way compare the order will always be of the last file.

Comment: How, the ordering of the rows from the three files are the same so i'm not sure why it changed. but also, i looked more carefully and I noticed that there were some rows that didn't get fixed.

Comment: Can you update your question with the issue you are noticing or better open a new question. It is difficult to understand the issue from comments.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit convoluted but gets the job done

```
 sort <(tail -n +2  A.csv) <(tail -n +2 B.csv) | 
 uniq -d | sort <(tail -n +2  C.csv) - |
 uniq -d | cat <(head -1 A.csv) -
```

Answer (score 0):

a 2-step approach:

```
$ comm -12 <(sort A.csv) <(sort B.csv) > tmp

$ comm -12 <(sort tmp) <(sort C.csv)
Animal, Color, Age
Cow, White, 3
Parrot, Blue, 2
```